# Regex to replace punctuation at the beginning and end of a string

Tags: java

How can I remove all punctuation except ' in the first character and last character of a string in java. I have tried using regex with replaceFirst() but didn't succeed.

For instance, !abc3@ would become abc3,
!!abc3@@ would become !abc3@
and 'abc3' would still stay as 'abc3'

This is what I have come up with 
`.replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z0-9']", "").replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z0-9']$", "")`

but the compiler seems to not accept it. I get a "cannot find symbol" error.

Comment: can you please show us what you tried and some input output example?

Comment: What did you try?  How did it not succeed?

Comment: You should show example inputs and outputs for an accurate answer.

Comment: This is what I have done : ` .replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z0-9']", "").replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z0-9']$", "") `

Comment: Thanks for showing your current approach, but please also describe why your current approach isn't satisfactory. In other words, provide an examples where your code _does_ and _doesn't_ work.

Comment: The compiler seems to not recognize the expression. I get a "cannot find symbol error".

Comment: You need to provide your complete code. I think your approach is generally correct but you have a syntax issue somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex the solution is (your solution):

```
        String in = "!abc3@";
        String out = in.replaceFirst("^[^a-zA-Z0-9']", "").replaceFirst("[^a-zA-Z0-9']$", "");
        System.out.println("result: " + out);
```

A non-regex answer would be simpler and likely much faster.

```
        String in = "!abc3@";
        String out = in;
        if( (!in.isEmpty()) && (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(in.charAt(0))) )
            out = in.substring(1, in.length());
        if( (!out.isEmpty()) && (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(out.charAt(out.length() - 1))) )
            out = out.substring(0, out.length() - 1);
        System.out.println("result: " + out);
```